# How to print a word in reverse, letter by letter. Example "What is the best song right now" > "won thgir gnos tseb eht si tahW

Tags: python

prompts the user to enter a sentence of at least 5 words. Include a test to ensure that the user has entered at least 5 words. Store the individual words as separate items in a list. Print the sentence in reverse order - word by word. The words must print in one line (not beneath each other). Insert spaces between the words. Example: "What is the best song right now" > "now right song best the is What" Print the sentence in reverse order - letter by letter. The words must print in one line (not beneath each other). Insert spaces between the words. # Example: "What is the best song right now" > "won thgir gnos tseb eht si tahW

This is what I have so far

```
Sentence = input(("Enter a sentence: "))
Word = Sentence.split(" ")
reverse_words[::-1]
length = len(words)
if length!=5:
    print("Error! Please enter only 5 words")
else:
    print(length)
    print(" ".join(reverse_words))
```

Comment: The problem says *at least* 5 words, not *exactly* 5 words.

Comment: You never set `reverse_words`. You should set it by slicing `Word`.

Comment: There's a couple of possibilities here. `"this is sparta"` `"siht si atraps"` `"sparta is this"` `"atraps si siht"`. Think about what makes each different from the other. Try generating each one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if u are satisfied

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reverse_sentence(sentence):
     sentence_list = sentence.split(" ")
     if(len(sentence_list ) < 5):
             print("Please, insert a sentence with at least 5 words")
             return
     print(" ".join(sentence_list[::-1]))
     print(sentence[::-1])
```

This will print both desired outputs:

```py
sentence = "What is the best song right now"
reverse_sentence(sentence) # "now right song best the is What"
                           # "won thgir gnos tseb eht si tahW"
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful

Answer (score -1):

You can reverse a string with the function `reversed`:

```
s='word'
for letter in reversed(s):
    print(letter, end="")
```

*output:*

```
drow
```

Similarly, a list can be reversed:

```
for i in reversed(list(range(0,4))):
    print(i, end="")
```

*output:*

```
3210
```

Comment: `range` doesn't produce a `list` in Python 3 (it's a dedicated sequence type of its own, with fixed memory overhead regardless of length). `reversed` just works on arbitrary sequences (plus anything else that defines an ordering, e.g. `dict`s in the most modern Python versions), producing an iterator that runs in reverse.

Comment: and that helps OP how?